# Datanucleus warning: Class was specified in persistence-unit but not annotated, so ignoring

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, jpa, datanucleus

When starting up my app I see for every class this warning:

```
WARN  [DataNucleus.MetaData] - Class com.mycomp.MyClass was specified in persistence-unit myPersistenceUnit but not annotated, so ignoring
```

The app starts up correctly so there is no direct issue, but I'm wondering where this coming form, and how to avoid id.

My persistence.xml looks like:

```
<persistence-unit name="myPersistenceUnit">
    <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine" />
        <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true" />
        <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true" />
        <property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreEnableXGTransactions" value="true" />
        <property name="datanucleus.jpa.addClassTransformer" value="false" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I'm running my app on Google App Engine with Spring.

But I can't find the origin of the warnings.
Something seems to be telling my app to do some check for all classes.

PS: I'm defining my entityManagerFactory as follows:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceUnitName("myPersistenceUnit");
    entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceUnitPostProcessors(new ClasspathScanningPersistenceUnitPostProcessor("com.mycomp.domain"));
    return entityManagerFactory;
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't including any < jar-file > or < class > tags in your persistence.xml, so my guess is that your application is searching for Entities in all the classes it can reach. Maybe you are mixing Entity with non-Entity classes in the same java package. You don't say much about the pacakges or your classes really.

Comment: indeed, and user doesn't put "exclude-unlisted-classes" anywhere there so accepts it to go off and scan his CLASSPATH.

Comment: I added <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes> to persistence.xml and that caused the warning to go away. The entity classes are scanned in the creation of Spring's LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean as shown in the question. Thanks for helping!